# Redis GETEX issue with python 'redis' library

Tags: python, redis-cluster, redis-py

I am using Python with VS code to connect to a AWS Redis Elasticache Cluster (6.2 which has GETEX). I am able to connect to the cluster fine and make a get call. I am also able to make a setex call in another method. However when I make a getex call with the code below :

```
def redis_getex(text):
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)              
        if(redis.ping()):
            return_id = redis.getex(text,100)
            if return_id is None:
                return None
            else:
                return return_id
        else:
            print("Redis Connection Failed")       
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

I get a error message, ever though the I can find the reference to the getex call

```
 'Redis' object has no attribute 'getex'
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: which version of redis-py?

Comment: version is 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

4.3.4. A quick un install and reinstall fixed it...Thanks